# Update Query not working C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

In this page only this query

```
c1.cmd.CommandText = "update mechprofile set mech_status ='busy' where mech_regid ='" + alotmech + "'";
```

is working, rest of the queries are not working.

```
public partial class customercare_alotmechanic : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Class1 c = new Class1();
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();

    int sno;
    string license;
    string status;
    string alotmech;
    string mechregid;
    string mrg;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {


                sno = Convert.ToInt32((Request.Form["sno"]));
                status = Request.Form["sta"];
                alotmech = Request.Form["Sel"];
                mrg = Request.Form["mechregid"];

                if (alotmech.Equals("Alloted"))
                {

                    c.con.Open();
                    c.cmd.CommandText = "update probprofile set Status = 'done' where Sno ='" + sno + "'";
                    c.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.con.Close();

                    c.con.Open();
                    c.cmd.CommandText = "update mechprofile set mech_status = 'free' where mech_regid ='" + mrg + "'";
                    c.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    c.con.Open();
                    c.cmd.CommandText = "update probprofile set mechregid = '" + alotmech + "' where Sno ='" + sno + "'";
                    c.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.con.Close();

                    c1.con.Open();
                    c1.cmd.CommandText = "update mechprofile set mech_status ='busy' where mech_regid ='" + alotmech + "'";
                    c1.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c1.con.Close();
                }




            }


            finally
            {
                string strScript = "<script>";
                strScript += "alert('ALOT MECHANIC PAGE..');";
                strScript += "window.location='problemstatus.aspx';";
                strScript += "</script>";
                Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("strScript", strScript);

            }
    }
}
```

In the above code update commands are not working... I have a form on a page with method=post and action se to this page on which update query runs.

Comment: How are the commands not working? Are you receiving an error? If so, what is the error? Or are you looking in the DB and seeing the `UPDATE` hasn't had any effect?

Comment: Also - it's a bad idea to build SQL strings in the manner you are doing - you are much better off using [parameterised queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

Comment: +1 for @ElRonnoco's comment about parametrised queries. Please people, every time you concatenate sql like that, a kitten dies :-)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... values are not passed as i wanted.... will get back with some improvement....

Comment: I would definitely add a 'catch' command to catch any errors that occur, that way you can see the error, and take some action depending on what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your parammeters' value is correct:

```
If your data type is Nvarhcar so you should use N before your constants data. i.e.
"... column= N'"+ value+ "'"
Or if your data type is int so don't use '. i.e.
"... column= "+ value
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the values of the variables you are suffixing to the query statement? For example, check whether sno, status, and mrg actually contain valid values before doing the update with those values. If any of them is null or contain an unacceptable value as regards to your table design, then the query will fail.

What's the error statement you get? I see that you have a try...finally but no catch. You should always catch exceptions to promote better error handling.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... values are not passed as i wanted.... will get back with some improvement